# I got banned from Programmer but for a mistake

Tags: support, closed-questions, post-ban

I had just 100 of reputation and I gave 50 points for a bounty. I din't know I could experience a ban because of that.

Now I read the following message if I try to post a question.
"Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See the Help Center to learn more."

Can I ask you to upvote any of my question? The system will lift the ban.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You weren't banned. Your account has an automatic block for asking new questions due to your other questions being down voted, closed, and/or deleted. You should read [this post on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) to learn more about the block and how to overcome it. At this time, you can still post answers, and posting high quality answers is one method to overcome the block. Another is to edit your posts that have been closed to improve them and get them reopened.

Comment: But I don't have a large amount of closed or downvoted Q or A.. are you sure the alghoritm is not simply wrong? I also wonder on this: "My account is in good standing how come I still get banned?

Since the ban is based on IP address as well, when you browse from a shared computer or from work location that give the same IP address to many end users it's enough that one get banned and all others are "banned" as well. To rectify this, just browse from a different location." - Maybe it's someone on my same ip...

Comment: @Sam The details of the algorithm aren't revealed, even to moderators. However, you have asked 5 questions on Programmers. Of these, you have a net question score of -5. Three questions were closed and 2 were deleted. It seems reasonable to say that indicates a pattern of low-quality questions that would trigger such a block.

Comment: @Sam see [What is the 'deleted recent questions' page in the user profile?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/185491/165773) for guidance on how to find your deleted questions